# "PInvokeStackImbalance was detected" from HDFDotNet 1.8.7

Tags: c#, pinvoke, hdf5

I have been attempting to update to the latest HDF5DotNet wrappers (1.8.7) and am getting the following warnings (when running in DEBUG mode from VS2010):

PInvokeStackImbalance was detected
Message: A call to PInvoke function 'HDF5DotNet!::H5Fopen' has unbalanced the stack.
This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature.
Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

I am using the pre-compiled binaries (HDF5DotNet assembly for .NET Framework 4.0 32-bit), but got the same result when I compiled from source.

Strangely, when executing my application that calls the HDF5DotNet wrappers in non-DEBUG mode, I see no problems.  I  did notice that between 1.8.6 and 1.8.7  all the calling conventions were switched from Cdecl to StdCall.  Could this be causing this?  I've seen other forums saying the CallingConvention should BE Cdecl...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, calling a `stdcall` function as `cdecl` or the other way round causes a stack imbalance. The main difference between these conventions is that with `cdecl` the *caller* is responsible for removing the arguments from the stack, with stdcall the *callee* is responsible.

I guess in release mode you have the same bug. But you don't get the error because some runtime checks are disabled. A native program would crash in most cases where you use the wrong calling convention, but it seems like the .net interop code has a more robust stack handling that masks this problem.

Comment: +1, this is accurate.  MDAs are disabled in the release build or without a debugger attached.  The warning is highly reliable and a serious problem.  Extra tricky because it can seem to work well until you make a seemingly small change to your code and crash hard.  Or worse, it works in the debug build and fails in release.  The change in the calling convention is indeed a classic fix.